# Send a custom emoji to another server with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So lets say a Discord bot is a member of server A and server B, and there is a custom emoji being hosted on server A. How do I get the bot to send the emoji on server B? I have seen bots such as MEE6 that can send custom emojis in DMs, so this surely must be possible.

I have tried both this:

```
message.channel.send('Test <:[emoji_name]:[id]>');
```

and this:

```
message.channel.send(`Test ${client.guilds.cache.get('[server_id]').emojis.cache.first()}`);
```

I used `.first()` since there is only one emoji in the server.

Both of these do not work. The emoji will appear in the server it is hosted in, but if I try to send it in any other server, it just shows the emoji name and/or ID. I cannot find any articles or questions that provide any other way of doing this. So in short, how do I get the bot to send an emoji to another server that the emoji isn't being hosted on?

Comment: Have you tried using `client.emojis.get("<Emoji ID>")`? If I remember correctly, that's the way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @wgumenyuk Thank you! This worked perfectly. If you turn this into an answer I’ll accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everyone facing the same issue, you can use `client.emojis.get("<Emoji ID>")`.

Here's a quick example:

```js
const someEmoji = client.emojis.get("<Emoji ID>");

message.channel.send(someEmoji);
```

Answer (score 4):

in discord.js v12 it is

```
const someEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get("<Emoji ID>");
```

Comment: The thing that was throwing me: you need to wait until the client is ready:
```client.once(Events.ClientReady, () => {
    console.log('Client ready')
    console.log(client.emojis.cache.get('<Emoji ID>'))
  })```